# How to correctly configure errorChannel in spring cloud (spring integration)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have a webapp in which I use Kinesis Stream with spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis and spring-cloud-starter-sleuth. What I would like to do is to configure the error handling properly. I would like to:

1. handle a message stream
2. if something go wrong in the point 1 handle the error (specifically for each stream)
3. create a errorChannel that handle all errors globally that happened in point 2.

Properties:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: destination1
      bindings:
        destination1-in-0:
          destination: destination1
          group: group1
```

This is the configuration code (in a class annotated with @Configuration):

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<MyStream> destination1() {
        return message -> {
            if (true) throw new RuntimeException("test");
            LOGGER.info("message: " + message);
        };
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "destination1.group1.errors")
    public void errorHandle(Message<?> message) {
        // TODO
        LOGGER.error("Handling ERROR: " + message);
        throw new RuntimeException("test2");
    }

    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel errorChannel() {
        ErrorHandler errorHandler = throwable -> LOGGER.error("Handling ERROR in errorChannel error handler: ");
        Executor executor = new ConcurrentTaskExecutor();
        PublishSubscribeChannel publishSubscribeChannel = new PublishSubscribeChannel(executor);
        publishSubscribeChannel.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        return publishSubscribeChannel;
    }
```

Please note that step 1 and step 2 are working. What it is missing is the third step.
After the Log "Handling ERROR: ..." I see another info log:

```
a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : Got an exception during sending a 'GenericMessage [payload=byte[142], headers={aws_shard=shardId-000000000000, id=bb56042b-240f-43b7-4c69-90de463bfeca, sourceData={SequenceNumber: 49645044161965514128638937043897685293310641448383676418,ApproximateArrivalTimestamp: Fri Oct 06 12:41:37 CEST 2023,Data: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=142 cap=142],PartitionKey: 2007189807,}, aws_receivedPartitionKey=2007189807, aws_receivedStream=mpeNotificationFraud, aws_receivedSequenceNumber=49645044161965514128638937043897685293310641448383676418, timestamp=1696588898426}]'
for the '{SequenceNumber: 49645044161965514128638937043897685293310641448383676418,ApproximateArrivalTimestamp: Fri Oct 06 12:41:37 CEST 2023,Data: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=142 cap=142],PartitionKey: 2007189807,}'.
Consider to use 'errorChannel' flow for the compensation logic.
```

Then there is this exception (Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: test2):

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@d13016c]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: test2
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.19.jar:5.5.19]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:113) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.19.jar:5.5.19]
```

What I want is that the errorChannel I have configured start working, so for this simple example it logs "Handling ERROR in errorChannel error handler".

Answer (score 1):

See docs how errors must be handled from now on: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_handle_error_messages

```
@Bean
public Consumer<ErrorMessage> myErrorHandler() {


spring.cloud.stream.bindings.destination1-in-0.error-handler-definition=myErrorHandler
```

Comment: I think that in this way the error handler is specific for the destination1 stream. I was looking for something that I can use for each stream as a fallback if the specific errorHandler for stream is not present or there is an error.

Running my app without the bean "errorChannel" I see this log:
No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.

I was thinking I could have used it but it's not working.

Comment: As far as I know the `destination1.group1.errors` doesn't work any more: we have to use that `error-handler-definition`. Then you  an just subscribe to the global `errorChannel` which is always there created by the framework for us.

Comment: How can we subscribe to the global errorChannel?

Comment: `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")`

Comment: tried the annotation @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel") above public void errorHandle but I cannot see the log of the bean "errorChannel" that I have create.
Anyway destination1.group1.errors works for spring cloud stream 3.2.9